# How to design this one to many database?

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I've been doing some reading on 'one to many' databases but I'm struggling understand the best way to implement a solution in my case.

I want a MySQL database to record which employees have read certain training hand-outs at work.

So I have a table of Employees. And I have a table of Hand-outs.

I want to record if the Employee has clicked to say they've read the hand-out.

My Employee table has ID, Name, Email.

My Hand-out table has ID, Title

Am I better adding a field to the Employee table that will contain a list of "Hand-out IDs" to show which hand-outs they've read?

I need to be able to easily search to show what percentage of Employees have read a particular hand-out and I think my method would make that very difficult?

I can't have separate fields on the Employee table such as Handout1, Handout2 etc as new hand-outs will be added regularly.

I'm sure this must be a common problem so wondered if someone could direct me to the best solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Look up [associative entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)/junction tables/bridge tables (there are many names)

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the heads up. Just reading about it now. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a bridge table here which records relationships between employee and hand-out records.  Something like this:

```
Employee_Handout (ID, EmployeeID, HandoutID)
```

Every time a new handout comes out, you would insert a record into the handout table.  Then, when a given employee reads that handout, you would insert a new record into the `Employee_Handout` table.  You probably don't need to persist non-reads, since they could easily be detected as being absent from the bridge table.

The primary key for this column would probably be `(EmployeeID, HandoutID)`, assuming you would only want a single record relating an employee reading a given handout.  This would also mean that a given employee/handout relationship could only be persisted once.

Comment: He needs a `UNIQUE(EmployeeID, HandoudID)` so there are no duplicates.

Comment: @LukasS The better thing to do then would be to make `(EmployeeID, HandoutID)` a primary key.

Comment: I would go with INT PK still, it's easier. Often what I do is just make a hash of concatenated multiple columns that should be kept unique and use that as PK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the great answer. Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Thanks :-)